# OpenVpn Server cannot ping Client

Tags: routing, openvpn

[My network setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onDhu.jpg)

I have installed OpenVpn Server on a windows 2012 box  behind a router.
After many tries i cannot ping the client from the server.

**From Client**

ping 10.8.0.1 successful

ping 192.168.0.1 successull

ping 192.168.0.x successful

**From server**

ping 10.8.0.4 successful

ping 192.168.1.116 UNsucceful

ping 192.168.1.x UNsuccessful

**server conf**

```
proto udp

dev tun

ca ca.crt"

cert VPNServer.crt"

key VPNServer.key"  

dh dh.pem"

topology subnet

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"

keepalive 10 120

cipher AES-256-CBC

persist-key

persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 6

explicit-exit-notify 1
```

**Server Route Table**

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.3      192.168.0.1    266
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.8.0.1    266
         10.8.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.1    266
       10.8.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.1    266
```

**Client conf**

```
dev tun
proto udp
remote my-server 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt"
cert Home.crt
key Home.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 7
```

**ClientRoute Table**

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.118     50
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.8.0.4    281
         10.8.0.4  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.4    281
       10.8.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.4    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.4    281
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.118    306
    192.168.1.118  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.118    306
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.118    306
```

Firewall is disabled on all boxes

IPEnableRouter is set to 1 on all boxes

I cant figure out what am i missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server doesn't have a routing table to 192.168.1-network, so it doesn't know what to do with those packets since.

You need to tell the openvpn server where 192.168.1 network is located, by using the "ccd" dir where you create a file named as the client certificate name, nd there you do a iroute to map where the 192.168.1. network should be attached to.

See the [routed LANs wiki page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans).

Comment: Thank you for your help.Please be more specific.I added every possible route to every interface-box.No joy.Its driving me crazy.

Comment: Follow the instructions of the routed LAN page that I linked to. Openvpn itself needs to understand the routing, so add "client-config-dir ccd" to server.conf, then in ccd/Home add the iroute 192... etc

Comment: Thank you. I solved it with your instructions.It was not working of a typo in ccd file